# Alignment of compound type objects in C90 and C99

Tags: c, struct, c99, unions, memory-alignment

Please consider the following types:

```
typedef struct { char myArray[300]; } MyStruct;
typedef union  { char myArray[300]; } MyUnion;

typedef struct { uint64_t x; } MyStruct2;
typedef union  { uint64_t x; } MyUnion2;

typedef struct { uint64_t x; char myArray[300]; } MyStruct3;
typedef union { uint64_t x; char myArray[300]; } MyUnion3;
```

I could find information about alignment and padding of members of compound types but I am not sure about objects of those type itself.

What alignment rules apply to objects of these types in RAM using C90 and C99 on X86 platform? Can the alignment change e.g. because the optimizer removes unused members (especially in unions)?

Comment: Alignment of objects is implementation defined. You should use compiler specific attributes, or _Alignas, if you want to set a specific value.

Comment: So there is absolutely no portable way to assure object aligment (e.g. by using members of a certain size etc.)?

Comment: _Alignas is portable, but it isn't C99.

Comment: What do you mean by 'C and C99'?  Do you mean 'C11 and C99' or 'C90 and C99' or some other combination of standards (or pre-standard C)?  But alignment is implementation defined.

Comment: I don't see any complex variables in your code. Do you mean compound types?

Comment: The compiler is not allowed to remove unused members from unions or structs.

Comment: The compiler cannot reasonably be sure a member is unused, hence will not remove "unused" members from unions or structs (actually, unions are another matter because what would "unused" mean?).

Comment: @Jonathan: C90 and C99.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes. Compounds. Some people use to call enums/structs/unions "complex types" and I get used to that :-(

Comment: @2501, Paul: Thanks. This is what I expected. Still I had a disucssion with someone insisting that removal of members could is possible... including consequences to the alignment... and alignment would be not implementation defined but would depend (in a portable way) from the largest member type. Do you have links that prove these theories are wrong? Also I would happy to upvote and/or accept your answer.

Comment: @Paul: See my last comment.

Comment: From the C standard (§6.2.5 Types): _Any number of derived types can be constructed from the object and function types, as follows: … array types … structure types … union types … function types … pointer types … atomic types …_   and _Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types. Array and structure types are collectively called aggregate types.46)_ Footnote 46 says: _46) Note that aggregate type does not include union type because an object with union type can only
contain one member at a time._

Comment: Incidentally, §6.2.5 says about structure types: _— A structure type describes a sequentially allocated nonempty set of member objects
(and, in certain circumstances, an incomplete array), each of which has an optionally
specified name and possibly distinct type._  And §6.5.2.1 Structure and union types says: _As discussed in 6.2.5, a structure is a type consisting of a sequence of members, whose
storage is allocated in an ordered sequence, and a union is a type consisting of a sequence
of members whose storage overlap._ Nothing about reordering or removing members — it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alignment of objects is implementation defined. You should use compiler specific attributes if you want to set a specific value.

The compiler cannot reasonably be sure a member is unused, hence will not remove "unused" members from unions or structs (actually, unions are another matter because what would "unused" mean?).

The only situation I can think of when the compiler can be sure, is when only static or automatic variables are created in a compilation unit of a struct, which are never passed to a function outside the compilation unit and one or more members are never used in statements. And probably I forgot something that defeats this reasoning.

I think that in all other cases the compiler cannot be sure a member is not used. For example, if it is passed to a function in another compilation unit the compiler cannot change the definition because the other function will rely on the definition and might be using members not used in this compilation unit.

For a union the compiler can never be sure because the memory of the members is shared.